# OpenGL texture precision / texcoord vs. attribute

Tags: opengl, interpolation, fragment-shader

I'm drawing a simple textured quad (2 triangles) using a one dimensional texture that hold 512 values ranging from 0 to 1. I'm using RGBA_32F on a NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M, GL_LINEAR interpolation and GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE.

I draw the quad using the following shader:

```
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler1D u_texture;

void main()
{
    float x =  v_texcoord.x;
    float v = 512.0 * abs(texture1D(u_texture,x).r - x);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v,v,v,1);
}
```

Basically, I'm displaying the difference between texture values and frag coordinates. I was hoping to get a black quad (no difference) but here is what I get instead:

[image: result]

I tried to narrow down the problem and try to generate a one dimensional texture with only two values (0 and 1) and display it using:

```
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler1D u_texture;

void main()
{
    float x =  v_texcoord.x;
    float v = texture1D(u_texture,x).r;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v,v,v,1);
}
```

and then I get:

[image: Linear interpolation]

Obviously this is not a linear interpolation from 0 to 1. The result seems to be split in 3 areas: black, interpolated and white. I tried different wrapping values with no success (but different results). Any idea what I'm doing wrong here ?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you decide the colour in the vertex shader, then pass that to the frag shader?

Comment: Yes, the texture is actually used to interpolate a function on every fragment. I only posted a stripped down simplified version here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a bit more, it seems the texture needs a small adjustement depending on texture size:

```
varying vec2 v_texcoord;
uniform sampler1D u_texture;
uniform float u_texture_shape;

void main()
{
    float epsilon = 1.0/u_texture_shape;
    float x = epsilon/2.0 +(1.0-epsilon)*v_texcoord.x;
    float v = 512.0*abs(texture1D(u_texture,x).r -v_texcoord.x);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v,v,v,1);
}
```

I guess this is related to wrapping mode but I did not find informations on how wrapping is enforced at GPU level.

Comment: This has nothing to do with wrapping, but with the fact that the the texcoord 0 is at the left _border_ of the leftmost texel, not it's _center_, and 1 is the right border of the rightmost texel, while you want a transition from the centers of these outermost texels.

Comment: As a side node: You might still be surprised of the result of your corrected code when using the 2 element wide [0,1] 1D texture and an output resolution of say 1024 pixels. There are some precision issues with texture sampling. Many modern GPUs use some fixed-point representation for the _texcoords_, so there is only a limited set of positions which can be sampled between two texels (typically 256). NVidia documents this in the CUDA docs, for example, and it is valid for OpenGL too.

Comment: You're totally right. Thanks a lot for these very useful explanations !