# Texture coordinate inaccuracy

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am getting what looks like a precision problem at 16 bit for texture uv. This might be common knowledge, and `texture` casting to normalized integer, but I could not find much¹ about that, nor would it make much sense to me (why degrade the coordinates at the last step?).

In real code (which is too long to show), this results in a texture bleed when zooming in too far, way before the expected issues for float32. The following demo has a lot of boilerplate, so here are the parts I think are important:

- The test texture is a 512x512 checkerboard of 8x8 tiles, green and blue.
- A square is rendered, with uv set to an 8x8 blue tile above the middle, sitting so it covers half the canvas.
- `const offset = -1 / (1 << bitsRequired);` slightly shifts these uv on the y-axis.
- `const zoom = 2 ** (bitsRequired - 14);` zooms in on the edge.

By construction, the uv offset is then set to a step that requires more than 16 bit. The zoom is chosen so exactly one green pixel should be rendered, without precision problems. However, at exactly 17 bit required precision, the pixel vanishes (at least for me, but it could be dependent on hardware/driver/whatever - if someone cannot reproduce, and it hasn't been mentioned already, please do).

At first, I thought I made a mistake. However, adding the rounding manually before the `texture` call, uncommenting the following, makes the green pixel line reappear:

```
vec2 texCoordRounded = vec2(
  (floor(vTextureCoord.x * 512.) + 0.5) / 512.,
  (floor(vTextureCoord.y * 512.) + 0.5) / 512.
);
```

Now I am confused. Did I miss something, or make a mistake? Does `texture` cast to some normalized integer? Why does this look like my precision runs out at 16 bit?

The following is copy&paste of the same code, with changed parameters (too cumbersome to parameterize this demo code):

With an offset requiring less than 16 bit, the green pixel line appears:

```js
const assert = (condition, message) => {
  if (!condition) throw new Error(message);
};

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
assert(gl !== null, `WebGL2 was unexpectedly not supported.`);

const testImage = new Uint8Array(Array.from(
  { length: 512 * 512 },
  (_, i) => (i % 16 > 7) !== (Math.floor(i / 512) % 16 > 7)
    ? [0, 0xff, 0, 0xff]
    : [0, 0, 0xff, 0xff],
).flat());
const bitsRequired = 16;
const offset = -1 / (1 << bitsRequired);
const vData = new Float32Array([
  -1, 0, 0, 0.5 + offset, 1, 0, 0.015625, 0.5 + offset,
  1, 2, 0.015625, 0.515625 + offset, -1, 2, 0, 0.515625 + offset,
]);
const zoom = 2 ** (bitsRequired - 14);
const projection = new Float32Array([
  zoom, 0,    0,     0,
  0,    zoom, 0,     0,
  0,    0,    -zoom, 0,
  0,    0,    0,     1,
]);

const indices = new Uint16Array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3]);
const texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 512, 512, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, testImage);

const vao = gl.createVertexArray();
gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);

const vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 8);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const vertexShaderSrc = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform mat4 projection;
layout(location = 0) in vec2 aPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 aTextureCoord;
out vec2 vTextureCoord;
void main(void) {
  gl_Position = projection * vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
}`;

const fragmentShaderSrc = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D sampler;
in vec2 vTextureCoord;
out vec4 fColor;

void main(void){
  // vec2 texCoordRounded = vec2(
    //   (floor(vTextureCoord.x * 512.) + 0.5) / 512.,
    //   (floor(vTextureCoord.y * 512.) + 0.5) / 512.
    // );
  // vec4 color = texture(sampler, texCoordRounded);
  vec4 color = texture(sampler, vTextureCoord);
  fColor = color;
}`;

const program = gl.createProgram();
assert(program !== null, `Program was unexpectedly \`null\`.`);

const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
assert(vertexShader !== null, `Vertex-shader was unexpectedly \`null\`.`);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSrc);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
assert(gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS), `Vertex-shader failed to compile:\n${gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader)}`);

const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
assert(fragmentShader !== null, `Vertex-shader was unexpectedly \`null\`.`);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSrc);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
assert(gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS), `Fragment-shader failed to compile:\n${gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader)}`);

gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);
assert(gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS), `Program linking failed:\n${gl.getProgramInfoLog(program)}`);

gl.useProgram(program);

const uniformLocationSampler = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'sampler');
gl.uniform1i(uniformLocationSampler, 0);
const uniformLocationProjection = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'projection');
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocationProjection, false, projection);

gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='256' height='256'></canvas>
```

Changing `bitsRequired` to `17` (only change) causes the problem, the green pixel line disappears:

```js
const assert = (condition, message) => {
  if (!condition) throw new Error(message);
};

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
assert(gl !== null, `WebGL2 was unexpectedly not supported.`);

const testImage = new Uint8Array(Array.from(
  { length: 512 * 512 },
  (_, i) => (i % 16 > 7) !== (Math.floor(i / 512) % 16 > 7)
    ? [0, 0xff, 0, 0xff]
    : [0, 0, 0xff, 0xff],
).flat());
const bitsRequired = 17;
const offset = -1 / (1 << bitsRequired);
const vData = new Float32Array([
  -1, 0, 0, 0.5 + offset, 1, 0, 0.015625, 0.5 + offset,
  1, 2, 0.015625, 0.515625 + offset, -1, 2, 0, 0.515625 + offset,
]);
const zoom = 2 ** (bitsRequired - 14);
const projection = new Float32Array([
  zoom, 0,    0,     0,
  0,    zoom, 0,     0,
  0,    0,    -zoom, 0,
  0,    0,    0,     1,
]);

const indices = new Uint16Array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3]);
const texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 512, 512, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, testImage);

const vao = gl.createVertexArray();
gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);

const vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 8);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const vertexShaderSrc = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform mat4 projection;
layout(location = 0) in vec2 aPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 aTextureCoord;
out vec2 vTextureCoord;
void main(void) {
  gl_Position = projection * vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
}`;

const fragmentShaderSrc = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D sampler;
in vec2 vTextureCoord;
out vec4 fColor;

void main(void){
  // vec2 texCoordRounded = vec2(
    //   (floor(vTextureCoord.x * 512.) + 0.5) / 512.,
    //   (floor(vTextureCoord.y * 512.) + 0.5) / 512.
    // );
  // vec4 color = texture(sampler, texCoordRounded);
  vec4 color = texture(sampler, vTextureCoord);
  fColor = color;
}`;

const program = gl.createProgram();
assert(program !== null, `Program was unexpectedly \`null\`.`);

const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
assert(vertexShader !== null, `Vertex-shader was unexpectedly \`null\`.`);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSrc);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
assert(gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS), `Vertex-shader failed to compile:\n${gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader)}`);

const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
assert(fragmentShader !== null, `Vertex-shader was unexpectedly \`null\`.`);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSrc);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
assert(gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS), `Fragment-shader failed to compile:\n${gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader)}`);

gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);
assert(gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS), `Program linking failed:\n${gl.getProgramInfoLog(program)}`);

gl.useProgram(program);

const uniformLocationSampler = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'sampler');
gl.uniform1i(uniformLocationSampler, 0);
const uniformLocationProjection = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'projection');
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocationProjection, false, projection);

gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='256' height='256'></canvas>
```

Activating the previously commented manual rounding before the `texture` call (only change) on what's still float32 causes the green pixel line to re-appear, fixing the problem, but why?

```js
const assert = (condition, message) => {
  if (!condition) throw new Error(message);
};

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');
assert(gl !== null, `WebGL2 was unexpectedly not supported.`);

const testImage = new Uint8Array(Array.from(
  { length: 512 * 512 },
  (_, i) => (i % 16 > 7) !== (Math.floor(i / 512) % 16 > 7)
    ? [0, 0xff, 0, 0xff]
    : [0, 0, 0xff, 0xff],
).flat());
const bitsRequired = 17;
const offset = -1 / (1 << bitsRequired);
const vData = new Float32Array([
  -1, 0, 0, 0.5 + offset, 1, 0, 0.015625, 0.5 + offset,
  1, 2, 0.015625, 0.515625 + offset, -1, 2, 0, 0.515625 + offset,
]);
const zoom = 2 ** (bitsRequired - 14);
const projection = new Float32Array([
  zoom, 0,    0,     0,
  0,    zoom, 0,     0,
  0,    0,    -zoom, 0,
  0,    0,    0,     1,
]);

const indices = new Uint16Array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3]);
const texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 512, 512, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, testImage);

const vao = gl.createVertexArray();
gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);

const vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 8);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const vertexShaderSrc = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform mat4 projection;
layout(location = 0) in vec2 aPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 aTextureCoord;
out vec2 vTextureCoord;
void main(void) {
  gl_Position = projection * vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
}`;

const fragmentShaderSrc = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D sampler;
in vec2 vTextureCoord;
out vec4 fColor;

void main(void){
  vec2 texCoordRounded = vec2(
      (floor(vTextureCoord.x * 512.) + 0.5) / 512.,
      (floor(vTextureCoord.y * 512.) + 0.5) / 512.
    );
  vec4 color = texture(sampler, texCoordRounded);
  // vec4 color = texture(sampler, vTextureCoord);
  fColor = color;
}`;

const program = gl.createProgram();
assert(program !== null, `Program was unexpectedly \`null\`.`);

const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
assert(vertexShader !== null, `Vertex-shader was unexpectedly \`null\`.`);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSrc);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
assert(gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS), `Vertex-shader failed to compile:\n${gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader)}`);

const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
assert(fragmentShader !== null, `Vertex-shader was unexpectedly \`null\`.`);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSrc);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
assert(gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS), `Fragment-shader failed to compile:\n${gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader)}`);

gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);
assert(gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS), `Program linking failed:\n${gl.getProgramInfoLog(program)}`);

gl.useProgram(program);

const uniformLocationSampler = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'sampler');
gl.uniform1i(uniformLocationSampler, 0);
const uniformLocationProjection = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'projection');
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(uniformLocationProjection, false, projection);

gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='256' height='256'></canvas>
```

---

[1]: Edit: I found a comment in an otherwise [unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711444/opengl-texture-precision-texcoord-vs-attribute) which supports my guess of sampling using normalized integers, but still no official documentation:

> Many modern GPUs use some fixed-point representation for the texcoords, so there is only a limited set of positions which can be sampled between two texels (typically 256).

Note that the comment is from 2014 (9 years old), and my guess would be the default is 16 bit normalized integer instead of 8 bit by now.

Edit2: I now also found this in the [directx d3d spec](https://microsoft.github.io/DirectX-Specs/d3d/archive/D3D11_3_FunctionalSpec.htm#3.2.4%20Fixed%20Point%20Integers) (thanks to [a blog post](https://www.reedbeta.com/blog/texture-gathers-and-coordinate-precision/))

> Texture coordinates for sampling operations are snapped to fixed point (after being scaled by texture size), to uniformly distribute precision across texture space, in choosing filter tap locations/weights. Weight values are converted back to floating point before actual filtering arithmetic is performed.

I still can't find any authoritative documentation for opengl/webgl though. It's getting more and more clear, that what's happening is exactly my guess, but where is the documentation, and is "uniform distribution" enough reason to cut off 8 bit of precision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why degrade the coordinates at the last step?

... because GPUs can do a few billion texture filtering operations per second, and you really don't want to waste power and silicon area doing calculations at fp32 precision if all practical use cases need 8-bit fixed point.

Note this is 8-bits of *sub-texel* accuracy (i.e. granularity for GL_LINEAR filtering between two adjacent texels). Selecting texels is done at whatever higher precision is needed (most modern GPUs can uniquely address 16K textures, with 8-bits of subtexel accuracy).

Comment: Thanks! I still don't fully understand the "why" (need to also convert from float once per those billion operations), but can see it's not unlikely there are valid reasons, which is enough for now. To tackle the immediate problem, is some operation (like rounding) in the fragment-shader normal, when magnifying to 256x or more (where the 1/512th texel offset in texture-space is visible), or is there a better trick?

Comment: Why -> Look at how much maths you need to do on component samples for a trilinear filter =)

Comment: There is a short demo in the question. How I understood it, it's a rounding-to-nearest-even issue, when being zoomed in enough (e.g. one texel is 256 pixels on screen). Fragments' interpolated uv in float will still be able to accommodate that, but 16.8 fixed-point won't. It would round to the texel border, and one of the two sides will then be wrong. Perhaps such zoom isn't common enough for there to be a default solution.

Comment: Yeah sorry - missed the shader code in the original post.

Comment: I accidentally linked a full [blog post](https://www.reedbeta.com/blog/texture-gathers-and-coordinate-precision/) about it, while searching for the openGL spec part, but only now read it (after realizing it's not an openGL-specific thing). Also I see the point with trilinear filtering - I'm on a pixel game, with `GL_NEAREST`, but it makes sense the hardware won't suddenly switch for just one case.

Comment: Yes, once you end up with a 256x zoom you're around the limits of what the sub-texel accuracy can give you. As mentioned on your other post, you're really in the realms of implementation-defined behavior - even the GPU float in shaders isn't IEEE strict, so implementations are free to choose e.g. rounding modes, reassociate some types of operation, etc.

Comment: Guess some rounding/clamping/whatever in the fragment-shader it is, to the middle of a texel, before passing the data for sampling. I can go to `precision highp float`, in which case I have a guaranteed float32+ (webgl2), and no precision problems yet at 256x zoom. Good thing about pixel games is, GPU is hardly ever a performance limit, but I need to avoid texture bleeding :)