# Prevent texture rounding error for pixel graphics

Tags: javascript, webgl2

To prevent XY-problems, I'll describe the problem, followed by my current idea for a solution. Given this has to have been solved a thousand times by other people, I need a sanity check, whether I am running down the completely wrong path, or not.

---

In 2D pixel graphics (`GL_NEAREST`), when translating by half of a screen pixel, rounding behavior determines the color of a fragment. This means frequently choosing the wrong texel.

From my understanding, in the following image:

- On the left side, fragments' UV-coordinates will be exactly between texels (by construction, UVs selecting size of the quad pixels from the texture).
- The rasterizer won't include some fragments (e.g. left side, red stripes, not shown on the right), due to conflict rules for seamless connections between triangles.
- Default rounding will only be correct, if UV-space up is also screen-space up. This fails immediately when rotating, see the right side.

[image: example1]

E.g. for a y-flipped texture, the selected texels are one row off. Clamping to prevent texture bleeds would result in one row being used twice, and one missing¹. When freely rotating sprites, these errors may occur for certain rows or columns.

I'm aware of two common approaches, which both seem to fail:

- Rounding vertices to pixel-corners, which I don't see working when sprites can rotate.
- Having transparent border pixels in the texture-atlas. This is a somewhat dirty patch, and has costs. It destroys power-of-two sized textures (unless increasing the size by four times), and required border-size depends on mipmap-level.

---

For 2D pixel-graphics, almost everything is a textured quad. Given this, my current idea is to render each quad slightly larger (to have both side's fragments included in the problem-case). I'd then manually round to middle of texels in the fragment-shader, and drop fragments, which would be outside of the intended texture.

Is this a bad idea? How do other people solve this?

---

---

(1): Example webgl code always needs a lot of boilerplate. The problem imho does not require a demonstration, but people do love clicking things which display something.

The following has y-flipped UVs, and clamps in the fragment-shader. To be able to see texels selected, a colorful texture is generated:

[image: texture]

The entire thing is on 8x8 pixels, using a quad constructed to be 5x5, upscaled for ease-of-view.

```js
const assert = (condition, message) => {
  if (!condition) throw new Error(message);
};

const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2', { antialias: false });
assert(gl !== null, `WebGL2 was unexpectedly not supported.`);

const distribution = (x) => Math.E ** (-((1.6 * x) ** 2));
const rollover = 11;
const getColors = (i) => [0, 1, 2].map(e => Math.round(0xff * distribution((((e + 0.5) + (i % rollover) / rollover * 3) % 3) - 1.5)));

const textureSize = 8;
const testImage = new Uint8Array(Array.from(
  { length: textureSize * textureSize },
  (_, i) => [...getColors(i), 0xff],
).flat());
const positionPerPixel = 2 / 8;
const selectionInPixels = 5;
const offsetY = -0.5;
const vertices = [
  [0,                 0 + offsetY],
  [selectionInPixels, 0 + offsetY],
  [selectionInPixels, selectionInPixels + offsetY],
  [0,                 selectionInPixels + offsetY],
].map(coordPair => coordPair.map(coord => (coord - 2) * positionPerPixel));
const pixelOffset = 2;
const normalizedCoordPerPixel = 1 / textureSize;
const textureCoords = [
  [0,                 selectionInPixels],
  [selectionInPixels, selectionInPixels],
  [selectionInPixels, 0],
  [0,                 0],
].map(coordPair => coordPair.map(coord => (coord + pixelOffset) * normalizedCoordPerPixel));
const vData = new Float32Array(vertices.map((e, i) => [...e, ...textureCoords[i]]).flat());

const indices = new Uint16Array([0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3]);
const texture = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 8, 8, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, testImage);

const vao = gl.createVertexArray();
gl.bindVertexArray(vao);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(1);

const vBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vBuffer);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(1, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 16, 8);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const iBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const vertexShaderSrc = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
layout(location = 0) in vec2 aPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 aTextureCoord;
out vec2 vTextureCoord;
void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(aPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
  vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;
}`;

const maxTextureCoord = Math.max(...textureCoords.flat());
const minTextureCoord = Math.min(...textureCoords.flat());
const fragmentShaderSrc = `#version 300 es
precision highp float;
uniform sampler2D sampler;
in vec2 vTextureCoord;
out vec4 fColor;

void main(void){
  vec2 clamped = vec2(
    clamp(vTextureCoord.x, ${minTextureCoord} + 0.01, ${maxTextureCoord} - 0.01),
    clamp(vTextureCoord.y, ${minTextureCoord} + 0.01, ${maxTextureCoord} - 0.01)
  );
  fColor = texture(sampler, clamped);
}`;

const program = gl.createProgram();
assert(program !== null, `Program was unexpectedly \`null\`.`);

const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
assert(vertexShader !== null, `Vertex-shader was unexpectedly \`null\`.`);
gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSrc);
gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
assert(gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS), `Vertex-shader failed to compile:\n${gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader)}`);

const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
assert(fragmentShader !== null, `Vertex-shader was unexpectedly \`null\`.`);
gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSrc);
gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
assert(gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS), `Fragment-shader failed to compile:\n${gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader)}`);

gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);
assert(gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS), `Program linking failed:\n${gl.getProgramInfoLog(program)}`);

gl.useProgram(program);

const uniformLocationSampler = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'sampler');
gl.uniform1i(uniformLocationSampler, 0);

gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

gl.drawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, 6, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' width='8' height='8'></canvas>
```

The code is a slightly modified copy&paste from a [related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75190029/texture-coordinate-inaccuracy) (limited subtexel precision leading to UVs snapping to exactly half-way between texels). Therefore, some oddities may still be left in there.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but why not just increase the resolution of the texture?

Comment: I'm not sure, how that would improve anything. The issue is, that for e.g. the demo image's left side, lower left pixel, the UVs for the fragment would be precisely at the border of the desired texture. In an y-flipped scenario, rounding would select a texel outside of the desired texture. Increasing the resolution on screen (plus clamping) should make the issue less prevalent, but isn't an option. In the application, zooming is possible, and it would be preferable if 1:1 (or even lower) would not produce artifacts.